# Bash : check if ssh key connection is well setup

Tags: bash, ssh, connection, key

First, I'm sorry if this post duplicate another one. But if it does, I did not find it through my research :)

The problem is :

I need to check if I can connect to a server via ssh without using a password. I know you need to make a key to do so, but I just want to check if it was well done in bash.

I found a lot of things about how to test availability of the server, etc ... but not what I was searching for.

Thanks in advance for your answer ;)

T.F.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution after a new try ^^ (yeah, short time between post and solution ;) )

```
echo -e "Checking if you have setup a key for serve ssh connection ..."
ssh -o BatchMode=yes uname@host 'exit'
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo -e "You're done"
else
  echo -e "Set up a ssh key please "
fi
```